# Trying to write a calling batch file but keep getting "cannot find" error

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd, wildcard

I am trying to write a batch file that calls another which replaces two files in a directory. Here is my code:

```
set mmcIpath="C:"*"\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances"

call C:\%mmcIpath%\spc_we_replace_CED+CEDU.bat
```

Whenever I set the temporary environment variable, it says the directory cannot be found.

--ADDITIONAL INFO--

I run a Minecraft launcher called MultiMC5; it has a feature which runs commands - but only one command, for some reason. So I wanted it to call a batch file to run multiple commands.

My main batch file is in "C:...\MultiMC\instances", but I want the program to be able to call it. It cannot, as it works within a subdirectory called "CED (210 mods-)". So I placed another batch in the subdirectory to **call the main one** (I wanted to do the same for a second subdirectory called "CEDU (300+ mods-)"). I got this error: "The system cannot find the path specified.". It happened when I set the **path**.

I'm using Windows 8.1 and have searched for tips on how to use wildcards and on how to use FOR loops, but none of the wildcard methods have worked for me and I cannot understand FOR loops at all. I have also tried to remove and add things like quotation marks in an attempt to fix it, but that didn't work either.

**My question:**

Is the set command compatible with wildcards and if so, how do I get this to work?

Comment: `set` sets a variable to a string. `*` is a valid character in a string. But you cannot use a path with a wildcard. Why do you want to use a wildcard?

Comment: I want to do that so that I can put the directory wherever I need to without changing the batch file all the time. It seemed to work earlier with a batch file that had the exact same code (though for some reason I could not check as the pause command wouldn't work).

Comment: There is a way to search for a directory - but this may take several minutes. Is this an option for you? The better you can tell, where that directory is, the faster the search will be. (for example: is it always below %USERPROFILE%?)

Comment: It is, though when on other computers I want to run it off a USB stick (trying to use wildcards in drive names). The reason why I'm using a chain of batch files is that a program runs commands inside a directory, but I want to keep my main batch outside as it's quite a big one (takes up a lot of memory as it has to exclude many files and do other stuff as well). So I have tried to use a smaller batch file inside the directory to call it, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: -sorry, new to StackExchange- by "It is", I meant that it is under %USERPROFILE% and is in the Documents folder (the program exists within a bunch of "fixed" directories, otherwise it would not work).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that the main batch file can be on any drive and you want to call other batch files with a path relative to the location of main batch file. Is that correct?

You can get the drive with `%~d0`, path with `%~p0` and drive + path with `%~dp0`. See the example below and execute this little batch file stored in several different directories:

```
@echo off
echo Batch is stored on drive %~d0
echo in the directory %~p0
echo resulting in path %~dp0
```

So you can use argument 0 referenced by %0 containing always name of batch file with full path using the syntax above explained in help of command `FOR` displayed with entering `for /?`in a command prompt window to call the other batch files with a path depending on path of the main batch file.

Comment: Okay... ...only problem is, my main batch file is in the parent directory (see above comment - under above post)...

Answer (score 0):

Now what we have here is a classic [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - being asked about a solution, not the underlying issue.

Here's a possible resolution:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set mmcIpath="C:"*"\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances"
set "mmcIpath=U:\\.*\\mmc-stable-win32\\MultiMC\\instances"
SET "targetbat=spc_we_replace.bat"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b/s /ad "%mmcIpath:~0,3%"^|findstr /e /i /r /c:"%mmcIpath%" '
  ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%%a\%targetbat%" (
  ECHO CALL "%%a\%targetbat%"
  ECHO GOTO nextstep
 )
)

:nextstep

GOTO :EOF
```

I've left the original setting of `mmcIpath` in place, and replaced it with a form to suit my system.

The approach is to execute a `dir/s/b/ad` command (directory, basic format, with subdirectories, directory names only) and filter it using `findstr`. I chose switches `/i` (case-insensitive) `/e` (must end with string) `/r` regular-expression `/c:` (following is one string to be matched).

The regex is constructed according to `findstr`'s rules - `\` needs to be doubled if it is to be used as a literal; `.*` means 'any number of any character'

This should provide a list of literal directory names which get through the filter. Look in the directory found for the filename, `call` the target file if found. The required CALL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO CALL` to `CALL` to actually execute the files.

The following `ECHO GOTO` is there to show that the loop can be broken after finding the first target file, if desired. You havent't indicated whether you want to run only the first or run all of the targets found.

---

Here's my test source. I use `U:` for testing data. Your system would likely be different.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "mmcIpath=\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances"
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,4) DO MD u:\%%a%mmcIpath% 2>nul
FOR /l %%a IN (2,2,4) DO COPY NUL u:\%%a%mmcIpath%\spc_we_replace.bat 2>NUL >nul
ENDLOCAL
ENDLOCAL


@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set mmcIpath="C:"*"\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances"
set "mmcIpath=U:\\.*\\mmc-stable-win32\\MultiMC\\instances"
SET "targetbat=spc_we_replace.bat"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b/s /ad "%mmcIpath:~0,3%"^|findstr /e /i /r /c:"%mmcIpath%" '
  ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%%a\%targetbat%" (
  ECHO CALL "%%a\%targetbat%"
  ECHO GOTO nextstep
 )
)

:nextstep

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that the first section is merely establishing `u:\1\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances` to `u:\4\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances` then creating a dummy file `spc_we_replace.bat` in `u:\2\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances` and `u:\4\mmc-stable-win32\MultiMC\instances`.

The string assigned to `mmcIath` in the second section is according to `findstr`'s syntax rules - each `\` is doubled, `.*` means "any number of any character". You would have to modify that string to suit your system. Note that `"%mmcIpath:~0,3%"` gratuitously takes the first 3 characters from the string. In my case, that would be `U:\`. YMMV

Comment: -sigh- My issue is that I want to replace some Minecraft mod files automatically in some of my directories. I have multiple files to replace, so I tried to use a program (it's a launcher called MultiMC5) to do this. However, it can only execute one command - no more. So I wanted it to call the main batch, as I have loads of instances, so I made one that is universal to the instance folders. But then I figured out that the program only works within the instance directory, not the parent (where the file is). So I tried to use a short chain of batch files and that didn't work either.

Comment: Also, I tested yours, but it didn't work (got another "cannot find path specified" error). Do I have to tweak it myself?